# Have the number of riddles reduced after sandbox?

Tags: discussion, sandbox, data-explorer

Is there any data about the number of riddles posted before and after sandbox?

Also, what is the average upvotes given to riddles before and after sandbox? It could be nice to have both of these numbers to see the impact of the sandbox.

What is the ratio of riddles posted to other types of puzzles? After a few days, sandbox would be plenty of riddles, so nobody would like to see it .

Finally, how much users have checked the riddles in sandbox per day? If it is less than 100 per day, then there is no use of sandbox.

Comment: The sandbox is still fresh, you might want to wait for a few weeks or more to really see the impact of the Sandbox.

Comment: It's only been a couple days. Also, 100 users per day would be insane. The _entire site_ sometimes doesn't see 100 active users a day.

Comment: @Emrakul , that what I am trying say .we are few people, who see the riddle in sandbox and we are the same people who see it when it gets posted.So Who are the users who get the benefit  of seeing only quality riddles ??

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, but since we are redirecting every user, old or new, to the Sandbox, everybody is benefitting from it.

Comment: @IAmInPLS How ? We are using memory of servers by posting it twice..

Comment: There are many people who doesn't use 'Puzzling meta' but prefer to use only PSE main site. And sandbox doesn't take care of the fact that who sees the riddles. It is to ensure that we collect the high quality riddles on our main site. So that when someone in future browse through the [tag:riddle] tag, then he sees good riddles having different concepts and ideas.

Comment: @manshu future means say around 50 days , in 50 days can't the riddle posted in S.E be deleted ??Where many people see (according to you) , and even can downvote to close . So any way" if someone in future browse through the riddle tag",they will getting only good riddles . Think this way once..

Comment: @manshu Or lets come to this idea let all the riddles less 10 votes be deleted from S.E , Do you think this will work ??

Comment: Here the problem is that the bad riddles weren't getting closed earlier. That was the reason Sandbox has been created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's too soon to be able to empirically evaluate any data about the sandbox.  Data on data.stackexchange.com is only updated weekly, so many of the riddles posted to the sandbox won't even be in that data yet.

Subjectively, however, it appears to me that the sandbox is having the desired effect and is working well.  From my own perspective, it seems that the quality of riddles on the main site has increased significantly.

It seems that most of the riddles posted to the sandbox are making it through to the main site, but I think the sandbox's effect is to discourage those without a well-thought-out riddle from posting at all.  If I realize that my riddle is unlikely to pass muster in the sandbox, I won't bother posting it at all.

I thought that after the first couple of days, people would stop checking the sandbox, but there still appears to be lots of activity, and riddles are getting voted up.  We will see how things go as we continue with the sandbox, but so far it looks quite promising.

I think the number of people checking the sandbox is irrelevant, if it is having the desired effect.  And there are always people who aren't even aware that meta exists, who will only see the riddle on the main site.

From a quick review of [the riddle tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), I would say riddle volume *has* decreased since the sandbox.  We were averaging probably at least 5 riddles a day (one recent day had 20), and we've had 5 riddles posted since the sandbox came into effect.  But I would argue that the number of *decent* riddles has remained fairly constant.

There's my thoughts on the matter.  I don't know if they help at all.